# Difference between black and blue eml327 diagnostic tool

Tags: obd-ii, cel, diagnostics, scan-tool, elm-327

I've recently bought an Alfa Romeo 147 1.6TS 2001 105hp(77kw), and the previous owner had an instrument, or gauge, or mileage table replaced along with electrical window and mirror button table on passenger side.

So in order to fix the errors and reset mileage on dashboard they told me that I need to do a proxy alignment, basically on every electrical device that gets replaced I need to do a proxy alignment on my car.

But there are 2 different diagnostic tools that people say can do that, but opinions are different from person to person, one says the blue can do that, others say the black version can do that.

**Here is the black version**

[image]

**Here is the blue version**

[image]

They are supposed to be the same by specifications but people say they are different by manufacturing so I don't know which one should I get and use.

Does anyone have experience in proxy alignment and resetting errors and which one should I get?

**Product Links**

[**Link to the Black Tool**](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2016-ELM327-USB-OBD2-Auto-car-Diagnostic-Tool-ELM-327-V2-1-USB-Interface-OBDII-CAN/32663723088.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_8,searchweb201602_1_10057_10056_10065_10037_10055_10054_10069_10059_10058_9134_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_4&btsid=03ffa8b3-9edd-4a34-a78b-303d2f2c598f)

[**Link to the Blue Tool**](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Vehicle-Diagnostic-Tool-OBD2-OBD-II-Vgate-ELM327-USB-OBD-Scan-USB-Diagnostic-Scanner-Work-With/32419732923.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_8,searchweb201602_1_10057_10056_10065_10037_10055_10054_10069_10059_10058_9134_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_4&btsid=03ffa8b3-9edd-4a34-a78b-303d2f2c598f)

Comment: Why does one appear to be an OBDI (bottom) and the other to be an OBDII?

Comment: Well i don't know, from the specifications both are supposed to be OBDII and supports all interfaces, like reseting errors, proxy, airbag, changing mileage, etc...

Comment: Do you have links to the individual products?

Comment: The products where are images from are on my language (Serbian) so i found you this one from aliexpress, they looks like they are the same. I put the links in the question.